# Как увеличить количество потоков и при этом не замедлять программу

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Необходимо что бы потоки выводились по порядку и это код

```
using System.Threading; 
class MyThread { 
  public int Count; 
  public Thread Thrd; 
  public MyThread(string name) { 
    Count = 0; 
    Thrd = new Thread(this.Run); 
    Thrd.Name = name; 
    Thrd.Start() ; 
  } 

  void Run() { 
    Console.WriteLine(Thrd.Name + " начат."); 
    do { 
      Thread.Sleep (500);
  Console.WriteLine("В потоке " + Thrd.Name + ", Count = " + Count); 
      Count++; 
    } while(Count < 10); 
    Console.WriteLine(Thrd.Name + " завершен."); 
  } 
} 
class MoreThreads { 
  static void Main() { 
    Console.WriteLine("Основной поток начат."); 

    MyThread mt1 = new MyThread("Поток 1"); 
    MyThread mt2 = new MyThread("Поток 2"); 
    MyThread mt3 = new MyThread("Поток 3"); 
    do { 
      Console.Write("."); 
      Thread.Sleep(100) ; 
    } while (mt1.Count <10 ||
             mt2.Count <10 ||
             mt3.Count < 10); 
    Console.WriteLine("Основной поток завершен."); 
  } 
}
```

```
    Был доработан
```

```
using System.Threading; 

class MyThread { 
  public int Count; 
  public Thread Thrd; 
  public int number;

  public MyThread(int number) { 
    Count = 0;
    this.number = number;

    Thrd = new Thread(this.Run); 
    Thrd.Name = "Поток " + number; 
    Thrd.Start(); 
  } 

  void Run() { 
    Console.WriteLine(Thrd.Name + " начат."); 

    do { 
      Thread.Sleep(number * 100);

      Console.WriteLine("В потоке " + Thrd.Name + ", Count = " + Count); 
      Count++; 

      Thread.Sleep(500 - (number * 100));
    } while(Count < 10); 

    Console.WriteLine(Thrd.Name + " завершен."); 
  } 
} 

public class MoreThreads { 
  public static void Main() { 
    Console.WriteLine("Основной поток начат."); 

    MyThread mt1 = new MyThread(1); 
    MyThread mt2 = new MyThread(2); 
    MyThread mt3 = new MyThread(3); 
    do { 
      Console.Write("."); 
      Thread.Sleep(100) ; 
    } while (mt1.Count < 10 ||
             mt2.Count < 10 ||
             mt3.Count < 10); 
    Console.WriteLine("Основной поток завершен."); 
  } 
}
```

И теперь потоки возводятся по порядку 
 поток 1 
 Поток 2 
 Поток 3

поток 1 
 Поток 2 
 Поток 3
  А не :

поток 3 
 Поток 2 
 Поток 1

поток 2
 Поток 3 
 Поток 1

Но если выводить большее количество потоков к примеру 10
То время выполнения будет расти

Вопрос : как организовать программу так что бы выводя большое количество потоков по порядку 
1.
2.
3.
1.
2.
3.
Не увеличевать время выполнения.
Т.е. мое решение для упорядоченного вывода потоков создаёт проблему при увеличении количества потоков.

P.s. надеюсь проблему изъявил доходчиво.

Comment: А сколько у вас процессоров/ядер? В любом случае, если потоки не ждущие, а работающие, то как только начнется (дорогостоящее) переключение потоков, то вы тут же получите замедление. Потоков не рекомендуется делать больше, чем процессоров/ядер, да и то - если на машине работает только одна ваша программа.. Да, если вам нужна конкретная последовательность - нужна синхронизация потоков (через те или иные примитивы синхронизации). Никакими искусственными задержками выполнения вы конкретной последовательности не добьетесь.

Comment: У меня 4 потока на ядро. Я понимаю что искусственные отсрочки это не решение и поэтому  я ищу способ  как упорядочить вывод без синхронизации потоков.  Возможно данная опция реализованна в каких-нибудь яп т.е. Мне интересен именно алгоритм

Comment: Нет уж, вы определитесь. Если вы хотите упорядочить, то вы должны синхронизировать потоки каким-то образом. Не задержками, конечно, а какими-нибудь семафорами или ещё как-то, но синхронизация всё-равно нужна. Поскольку потоки могут выполняться довольно произвольное количество времени и вам надо как-то узнать, что предыдущий поток завершился. Честно говоря, не понимаю, зачем вам это надо, если задачи должны выполняться последовательно, то зачем им параллельные потоки?

Comment: `как упорядочить вывод без синхронизации потоков` - никак, синхронизация для упорядочивания и нужна.

Comment: Ну, например, ставите счетчик и семафор. Потоки по готовности обращаются к счетчику, и выводит тот, чей номер равен номеру счетчика, причем он же и увеличивает счетчик, разрешая работу следующему. Или с помощью уведомлений или каких-то иных методов синхронизации (литературы хватает). Только как написал CrazyElf - зачем при этом параллельность? :)

Comment: Благодарю всех за внимание судя по всему синхронизация это единственный выход. public ThreadPriority Priority так же не решили мою проблему.